# Ionic2 not recognized as external command

Tags: ionic-framework

I am installing ionic 2 on my Computer. Already installed Node js 0.12 with npm.
I succeed to install ionic 2 but when I check using my cmd it just gives Error "Ionic not recognized as external command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear enough. I would like you to tell more about the error.

Looking at the "not recognized as external command". It looks like you have not added ionic PATH as environment variable.

You can also try to clean the npm cache and re install ionic, it should work. Had a similar issue some time back. It had worked.